# Disabling code for release build in Android Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have const in code that contains some important information:

```
const val IMPORTANT_CONST = "KEY INFORMATION"
```

I'm using this const only for debug mode and only temporary (after some time I'll remove it). For now, I'm using build config flag to know if I need to use this const.

How can I hide this const or replace value to an empty string for my release build variant?

Comment: why don't you user firebase remote config to that you can change it anytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add it as a `BuildConfig` field:

In your app gradle script:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        buildConfigField("String", "IMPORTANT_CONST ", "\"\"")
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField("String", "IMPORTANT_CONST ", "\"my secret stuff\"")
    }
}
```

And in your code:

```
Log.i("MyApp", "IMPORTANT_CONST = " + BuildConfig.IMPORTANT_CONST );
```

Comment: Is this approach safe? I want to be sure that no one can access the value of this const in the release build

Comment: @KacperOpyrchał: The secret string won't be present in the release build. It will be an empty string (or whatever bogus value to choose to give it). So this is safe as long as you don't give people access to your debug APK or your gradle script.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the constant in gradle like this:

```
        android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "IMPORTANT_CONST", "\"KEY INFORMATION\""
        }

        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "IMPORTANT_CONST", "\"\""
        }
    }
}
```

You can access this variable using `BuildConfig.IMPORTANT_CONST`

Answer (score 0):

Use `BuildConfig` which will provide build variant based on your gradle properties.

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
       //Set your constant 
    } else {
         //replace constant value   
    }
```